# d3.js not being able to visualiza a large dataset

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I need some suggestions on using d3.js for visualizing big data. I am pulling data from hbase and storing in a json file for visualizing using d3.js. When I pull the data of few hours the size of json file is around 100MB and can be easily visualized by d3.js but the filtering using dc.js and crossfilter is little slow. But when I pull the dataset of 1 week the json file size becomes more than 1GB and try to visualize using d3.js, dc.js and crossfilter then the visualization is not working properly and the filtering is also not possible. Can anyone give me any idea whether there is a good solution to this or I need to work on different platform instead of d3?

Comment: I've answered this question a few times over the years.  I recommend you go and read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg193983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Using_Canvas_AndOr_SVG).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely agree with what both Mark and Gordon have said before. But I must add what I have learnt in the past months as I scaled up a dc.js dashboard to deal with pretty big datasets.

One bottleneck is, as pointed out, the **size** of your datasets when it translates into thousands of SVG/DOM or Canvas elements. Canvas is lighter on the browser, but you still have a huge amount of elements in memory, each with their attributes, click events, etc.

The second bottleneck is the **complexity** of your data. The responsiveness of dc.js depends not only on d3.js, but also on crossfilter.js. If you inspect [the Crossfilter example dashboard](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/), you will see that the size of the data they use is quite impressive: over 230000 entries. However, the complexity of those data is rather low: just five variables per entry. Keeping your datasets simple helps scaling up a lot. Keep in mind that five variables per each entry here means about one million values in the browser's memory during visualization.

Final point, you mention that you pull the data in JSON format. While that is very handy in Javascript, parsing and validating big JSON files is quite demanding. Besides, it is not the most compact format. The [Crossfilter example data](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/flights-3m.json) are formatted as a really simple and tight CSV file.

In summary, you will have to find the sweet spot between **size** and **complexity** of your data. One million data values (size *times* complexity) is perfectly feasible. Increase that by one order of magnitude and your application *might* still be usable.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark says, canvas versus DOM rendering is one thing to consider. For sure the biggest expense in Web visualization is DOM elements.

However, to some extent crossfilter can mitigate this by aggregating the data into a smaller number of visual elements. It can get you up into the hundreds of thousands of rows of data. 1GB might be pushing it, but 100s of megabytes is possible.

But you do need to be aware of what level you are aggregating at. So, for example, if it's a week of time series data, probably bucketing by the hour is a reasonable visualization, for 7*24 = 168 points. You won't actually be able to perceive many more points, so it is pointless asking the browser to draw thousands of elements.